# What are is meaning of the eight line with respect to java?

Tags: c++, friend

I am Learning C++, presently previously I learned Java(there was no friend function concept over there). but here Currently on friends function section. 
BTW I know that Friend function allow to access the private and protected data of the class..

I know this  "::" scope qualifier. 
I know this ":?" conditional operator 
 
Box(): length(0) { }  //
This code line confused me.
is it same as blocks that we used in java or something else.

```
class Box  
{  
    private:  
        int length;  
    public:  
        Box(): length(0) { }  // ****What is this ?? ******
        friend int printLength(Box); //friend function  
};  
int printLength(Box b)  
{  
    b.length += 10;  
    return b.length;  
}  
int main()  
{  
    Box b;  
    cout<<"Length of box: "<< printLength(b)<<endl;  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: It's actually the 8th line.   In any event, it is an inline definition of a constructor for `Box` that accepts no arguments, has an initialiser list that initialises the member `length` to have a value of `0`, and does nothing else in the constructor body (between the `{}`).    If you had bothered to read any basic introductory material on C++ classes, you wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Comment: Also, the `printLength(Box)` method has a side effect, adding 10 to the length of b, and it doesn't really print the length at all. It acts more like a getter that also increases the length of Box.

Comment: It is constructor initialization

Answer (score 2):

That would be the default constructor for box, initializing the length member variable to 0 when run. If you tried to change the 0 in there to for example 12, all boxes would default to a length of 12. Look up a `C++ Constructor initialization list` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Line 8 to which you are referring is a non-default constructor. It gets called every time you create an object of the Box class. The "length(0)" part means that it's setting the length property of the that Box object to be 0.
If I were you, I would read about default constructors and non-default constructors. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor `Box` is defined which initialises `length` to 0

Answer (score 0):

It means you initialize `Box` Constructor having parameter `length` value `0`

General Syntax

```
Constructor_name : Parameter_name(value)
{

}
```